# Use update mehtod mapping from other mapper

Tags: mapstruct

I am having two Mappers

```
    @Mapper(uses= {ChildMapper.class})
    public abstract class ParentMapper {
        @Mappings...
        public abstract Parent dtoToParent(
                    final ParentDto dto);
                        
        @InheritConfiguration(name = "dtoToParent")
        public abstract Parent updateParentFromDto(
                final ParentDto dto,
                final @MappingTarget Parent parent);
    }
    
    @Mapper()
    public abstract class ChildMapper {
        Child dtoToChild(
                final ChildDto dto);
    
        Set<Child> dtosToChilds(
                final Set<ChildDto> childs);
    
        Child updateChildFromDto(
                final ChildDto dto,
                final @MappingTarget Child geo);
    }
```

When generating the implementation, how do I instruct MapStruct to use updateChildFromDto method inside the the method updateParentFromDto. It is generating with dtosToChilds which in-turn uses dtoToChild method.

Reason, when object is **present**, I want to **update** the properties rather than creating new, while when ***not present create new***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How would MapStruct even (in a generic way) recognise whether the object is present in the destination set?

But nothing is blocking you to write your own implementation to do that.. Something like this:

```java
    @Mapper()
    public abstract class ChildMapper {

        abstract Child dtoToChild(ChildDto dto);
    
        abstract Child updateChildFromDto( ChildDto dto, @MappingTarget Child geo);

   
        Set<Child> dtosToChilds(final Set<ChildDto> childs);
    

        // NOTE the void, I don't like to return a mapping target. MapStruct calls
        // update methods from update methods an regular methods from regular methods
        // using both in one signature, things tend to get blurry 
        void updateDtosToChilds(Set<ChildDto> childs, @MappingTarget Set<Child> target){
            for ( ChildDto child : childs {           
               Child targetChild = null; 
               // get matching child from target
               if ( targetChild != null ) {            
                  updateChildFromDto( child, targetChild );
               }
               else {
                  target.add( dtoToChild( child ) );
               }

            }
        }
    
    }
```

and like indicated above, don't do:

```java
        @InheritConfiguration(name = "dtoToParent")
        public abstract Parent updateParentFromDto(
                final ParentDto dto,
                final @MappingTarget Parent parent);
```

but rather

```java
        @InheritConfiguration(name = "dtoToParent")
        public abstract void updateParentFromDto(
                final ParentDto dto,
                final @MappingTarget Parent parent);
```

Comment: I had to do the same (even before viewing the answer). Had to find if each item inside the collection is already present or not, and update accordingly. Seems like no other easier way. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. See: https://mapstruct.org/faq/#why-do-i-get-this-error-could-not-retrieve-mapper-annotation-during-compilation why this is not implemented in MapStruct.